# Vibrating hollow sphere

Tags: steel, vibration, metals, sound

I would like to make a hollow sphere that can vibrate like a tuning fork. It should go like this:

1. Place the sphere on a table
2. Strike the sphere with something like a spoon
3. The sphere vibrates (audibly) for more than 10 seconds

I bought a stainless steel hollow sphere with a diameter of 4 inches and thickness 2.5mm. But when I strike it, it vibrates for less than one second. And the only sound is from the striking itself.

Should I change the dimensions (like thickness) of the sphere, or something else?

Comment: You'd probably get more sound out of a vibrating shell, if it had a hole in it. If you want it to go for 10 seconds, having it on the table might be problematic too.

Comment: @jsotola fair, I edited the question

Comment: @PeteW what could make the table problematic?

Comment: could dampen the vibration. Maybe if you hit it exactly from the side (or exactly top down??), so the table contact point would be a vibrational node (and the plane of the vibration never changed), it might not. But all things being equal, the less stuff it touches, the better

Comment: What was the frequency you expected from your bell? (if you like math, try here - https://www.academia.edu/68829152/Free_and_Forced_Vibrations_of_Spherical_Shells)

Comment: So yes, change dimension and weight by a few tons, and hit it with a sledgehammer as hard as you can. And use a bell alloy.

Comment: The sphere is vibrating to eternity.  Issue is the vibration is chaotic and dissipating energy to anything it touches. You could try to increase stored energy from a single strike- measure force and deflection to get an idea of how much to load it and do the reverse to see how much you actually got back.  And finally: Ping pong balls bounce for a while by storing the energy in gravity instead of just deformation.

Comment: @Phil Sweet I would be happy to start with anything that's audible

Comment: Table will likely dampen vibrations very quickly. Suspending the sphere might help. The best would be hanging it on a string, but for the "siting on a table" feel, a flexible support with proper stiffness might work as well. For practical reasons, you need a base for it anyway, otherwise it will roll away.

Comment: I think the thickness will drive the frequencies very high, because I think the sphere, being supported all the way around, will be stiffer than an open-bottom shape (i.e., a hemispherical bell).  You may also want to get onto Matweb or similar and look up the dissipation factor of various stainless steels: I'm pretty sure that stainless is usually "dead" compared to something that rings well like hardened aluminum or steel.